# Django Form Not Rendering HTML from class HomeForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms

For some reason I cannot get my Django form to render. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I'm trying to get the `class HomeForm(forms.Form)` to render on the `myaccount/change.html` page and have been unsuccessful.

I'm new to Django so I might be missing a small detail somewhere but I thought I got everything covered from the djago documentation.

If anyone can help me out it would be gladly appreciated. Thanks!

## users/forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django import forms
from .models import CustomUser

class HomeForm(forms.Form):
    post = forms.CharField()
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
#    job_title = forms.IntegerField(label='2 + 2', label_suffix=' =')
#    yes = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
    tos_check = forms.BooleanField(required=True, label='I have read and agree to the Terms of Service.')
    age_check = forms.BooleanField(required=True, label='I am 21 years of age or older.')

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email')
        help_texts = {
            'username': '',
            'email': '',
#            'password1': 'None',
#            'password2': 'Test'
        }

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    tos_checktwo = forms.BooleanField(required=True, label='I have read and agree to the Terms of Service.')


    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'tos_checktwo')

#    class Meta:
#        model = CustomUser
#        fields = ('username', 'email', 'tos_check',)
```

## users/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from django import forms
from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm
from .forms import HomeForm

def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = HomeForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = HomeForm()

    return render(request, 'myaccount/change.html', {'form': form})


class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'
```

## pages/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from . import views

from .views import HomePageView, MyAccountView, AboutPageView, PrivacyPageView, ContactPageView

urlpatterns = [
    path('about/', AboutPageView.as_view(), name='about'),
    path('privacy/', PrivacyPageView.as_view(), name='privacy'),
    path('contact/', ContactPageView.as_view(), name='contact'),
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('myaccount/', MyAccountView.as_view(), name='myaccount'),
    url('avatar/', include('avatar.urls')),
    url('myaccount/', include('avatar.urls')),
]
```

## templates/myaccount/change.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You don't seem to have posted the relevant view. What is calling `get_name`?

Comment: Can you post the portion of your template you're using to display the form?

Comment: @JHRS Sure I just added the code. Thanks again.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm not sure, I thought referencing `form = HomeForm(request.POST)` would be enough?

Comment: Sir, I don't see any problem in the code shared. But here is 2 hints : 
1 - check if in base.html, you have included the block content.

Comment: That didn't answer my question. A view is called by a URL. You don't have any URLs pointing at `get_name`. What is supposed to be displaying it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Got it, I'm assuming something like this `path('get_name/', views.get_name),` would work?

Comment: I don't see a url calling your get_view function. If you don't have one that is probably the problem, otherwise can you post it here. What URL are you using to get to the form, and what happens when you attempt to go to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sir, I don't see any problem in the code shared. But here is 2 hints :

1. check if in base.html, you have included the block content.
2. add `print(form)` before the return in the view to see what you get (the print result will be on the terminal not the browser)

**edit :** 
You should add an url that calls the view : 
in url add this line :

```
path('testform/', view.get_name, name ='get_name')
```

and then on your brower, test the url `127.0.0.1:8080/testform/`

Comment: Hello and thanks for the quick response. I added `print(form)` to the view and I don't see anything from the form populate in the terminal.. any ideas my friend?

Comment: Tried what you said and no luck :/

Comment: replace 'render(request, 'myaccount/change.html', {'form': form})' by 'HttpResponse("Test rendering")'. If it works then something is wrong with your template that renders the form or the base.html.

Comment: got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you will need to include {% block content %} and {% endblock %} tags in your base.html file.

When you "extend" the base template, these tags indicate where the extra content should be inserted.
see tte [Template Inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#id1)

Answer (score 0):

@AlouaniYounes Looks like on base.html the my account page was being directed somewhere else. I made the fix to base.html and problem solved. Thanks!